# Power Automate - Update Work Item Error - Response in JSON Format -Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate, azure-boards

I am getting an exception when I am trying to update an existing work item **description**  with a link of SharePoint file in power automate. This SharePoint file had been created when an email with the attachment was received.

Please have a look at the flow and exception below

[image: Flow when creating file at SharePoint]
[image: Exception]

Can anyone please help me understand the issue?
Thanks,
Bee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you entered a wrong variable for the field `Work Item Id`. The field `Work Item Id` for step `Update a work item` should be the id of the work item to update.

I saw you set the field `Work Item Id` to variable `{x}workItemUrl`. If variable workItemUrl is not the work item id. The automate flow will fail with above error.

[image]

You can also check the log to see if the values you specified in the fields are correct.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, that's been exactly the problem. I also tried the solution you advised end to end, and finally was able to implement it yesterday. I am writing a full blog post over it, in case anyone else wants to achieve something similar.